# If every entry of a matrix A is bigger than every entry of a matrix B, is norm A bigger than norm B?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

The norm $\lVert A \rVert$ is different from the norm $\lVert A(x)\rVert$, right?

Just making sure that I am interpreting questions regarding matrix norm correctly.

I am asked to compare the norm of two $3 \times 3$ matrices $A$ and $B$.

The answer is that
$$\lVert B \rVert \leqslant  \lVert A \rVert, $$
but I notice that every entry of $A$ is bigger than or equal to every entry of $B$.  So, the intuition that the norm of A would be bigger leads to the correct answer, in this case.  Is this a *theorem*, though?  That would be useful.

Thanks,

Comment: It probably is a theorem.  Which matrix norm is that?

Comment: Does "bigger than or equal" entries mean in absolute value or in ordering as real (?) numbers?

Comment: @muaddib, no matrix norm is specified - so I inevitably ask the question of which norm to use, but I am only told that all norms are equivalent in a finite dimensional vector space.  (So I guess we could just stick with the usual 2-norm = square root of the largest eigenvalue of A*A = ||A||.)

Comment: @hardmath - in ordering, comparing entry a_ij vs entry b_ij.

Comment: @hardmath - just checked again.  both, in ordering and in absolute value.

Comment: I can't think of a counterexample.  It'd be nice to find one.

Comment: You need to know what it means for two norms to be equivalent. It means they induce the same topology. It will not help you compare the norms of two matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $||A||_P = (\Sigma_j\Sigma_i|a_{ij}|^p)^{1/p}$, if for any pair $|a_{ij}| \ge |b_{ij}|$ holds, I think $||A||_p \ge ||B||_p$

Comment: Ah, very nice @Dylan.  You are essentially treating the matrix as one long row vector and are applying the vector p-norm to it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi @Dylan - I was wondering how your proof above could translate to saying ||A(x)|| greater than or equal to ||B(x)||?  Do you think this is automatic, once we have the inequality for the matrices themselves?

Comment: @user246802 sor, not able to solve that. can you give the definition of ||A(x)| where x is a variable.|

Comment: Sorry for reopening this question. Maybe I'm missing something, but if that's the p-norm of a matrix then, the 2-norm of the identity matrix is 1 and with those calculations it gives $\sqrt{2}$...

Answer (score 0):

The result doesn't hold. You can consider
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \qquad B=\begin{pmatrix} -2&0\\0&-2\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then for all $a_{i,j} \geq b_{ij} $ for $1 \leq i,j\leq 2$. However, with the usual operator norm then $||A|| = 1 < 2 = ||B||$.

Even if you consider the ordering in absolute value (and allowing for complex entries) it does not work. Suppose that for $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, $|a_{i,j}| \leq |b_{i,j}|$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$ implies $||A|| \leq ||B||$. Then considering $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix} \qquad B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&i\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
we get that the $|a_{i,j}| = |b_{i,j}| $ but $||A|| = 2 \neq 1.84776 \approx ||B||$.